# Why does submitting a Formotus form to SharePoint on an internal network fail but work when submitted over VPN?

Tags: forms, sharepoint-2013, fiddler

I am having problems submitting Formotus forms to SharePoint on an internal network. The behaviour is very strange and Formotus support have been unable to help.

Basically, when on an internal network, using the Formotus Windows 8 app the forms fail to submit with what appears to be authentication issues. What is weird is that if you run Fiddler at the same time the form works fine from the same device. We have turned off firewalls and lowered security to a minimum to eliminate this as a possible cause.

Similarly if you use the same device and connect via a VPN it works fine. It also works fine when connecting to Office 365 or a server in a different domain.

Can anyone explain why we see a difference in behaviour on an internal network. I would have expected that if anything the complete opposite would happen where it would work internally but not externally? Why does Fiddler affect the behaviour?

This has had us stumped for the last couple of months. We have tried everything we can think of without success.

Comment: More details are needed-- what error messages are seen? What kind of authentication system is in use? A low-level network capture (e.g. wireshark) may help.

Comment: It just says incorrect credentials, but when Fiddler was activated and Formotus was added in Fiddler’s AppContainer Loopback Exemption, it all works. I am not familiar with wireshark but I will see if that would help